# Conflict resolution when merging rows in R data frame

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, rows

I have a data frame that contains macroeconomic data series which are split up over two separate rows, but overlap for a number of common time points.

```
Country   Series    T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  T8  ...
Japan     Series1   10  20  10  30  40  NA  NA  NA  ...
Japan     Series2   NA  NA  NA  35  40  30  30  20  ...
Korea     Series1   70  80  70  70  80  NA  NA  NA  ...
Korea     Series2   NA  NA  NA  70  85  80  75  70  ...
```

I would like to merge these rows into one, but for reasons too complicated to go into, the second series sometimes contains different values for the overlapping time points. I want to retain these values when merging the rows (and correspondingly discard the values of the first series).

```
Country   Series    T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  T8  ...
Japan     SeriesA   10  20  10  35  40  30  30  20  ...
Korea     SeriesA   70  80  70  70  85  80  75  70  ...
```

Does there exist some R function that allows merging of two rows within a data frame while preserving all values belonging to a either one of these rows in case there is a conflict?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you always want `NA` removed when the two series differ- is that correct?

If so, here's a simple way.

```
newseries<- series2
newseries[is.na(newseries)]<-series1[is.na(newseries)]
```

I deliberately created the `newseries` so as not to modify your input vectors.  Note that this always selects `series2` values except when the value is `NA` . If you find you need a more complicated way of selecting `series2` values over `series1` values, it'll take slightly more work.

EDIT: as Ananda pointed out, you'd need to wrap those lines in a loop which selects each country name in turn and extracts the desired rows.

Comment: +1. I took [a similar approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25622526/1270695), but with `na.locf` from zoo, but this doesn't really show how to extend it across all the values in "Country".

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly. I decided to go with this method since it does not require a separate package and is very intuitive. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Here's an idea that uses `na.locf` from "zoo":

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(mydf)[grep("Series2", mydf$Series), ]
#   Country  Series T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6 T7 T8
# 2   Japan Series2 10 20 10 35 40 30 30 20
# 4   Korea Series2 70 80 70 70 85 80 75 70
```

Comment: Bet this runs faster :-).  I really need to make more use of `zoo` in my work.

Comment: I had no idea `zoo` could do that! Thank you so much for this. I decided to use Carl's approach for my present project, though, since speed is not as important as self-explanatory code :)